# Any way to make a mouse listener automated?

Tags: java, user-interface

Lets say I have an array of {0,1,2} an I draw a random number. If random number is 2 for example I want  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){... to do code...} the code inside this to work. Any way to make it possible?

```
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
     lblNewLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //to do code
        }
     });
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Basically I want to execute the code inside mouseClicked without clicking.

Comment: Then take it *out* of `mouseClicked(...)` and into its own method. In your `mouseClicked` method, call this new method, and also call the new method when you want to call it on its own. Your question ***still*** remains very unclear, and you will want to read the [ask] and then improve it before it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about "simulating" a mouse click,

- see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html
- or implement a GUI test, using e.g. Jemmy framework

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, it sounds like you just want to execute a block of code programmatically and execute the same block when the mouse is clicked. Here's how to do that.

1. Put the code you want to execute in its own method.

```
function doThing() {
   System.out.println("Mouse click action performed");
}
```

2. Call your new method from within the click handler.

```
lblNewLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            doThing();
        }
```

3. When you want to simulate the mouse click action elsewhere, just call `doThing();`.